# Why do my Apache logs show two timezones

Tags: apache-http-server, time-zone, httpd

Dates from my apache log are correct(ish) but in two different time zones.

For example...

```
10.3.1.1 - - [26/Jan/2011:10:57:34 +0200] "GET /html/js/jquery/jquery.bidi.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4328 "http://dhl-translation.accountis.net/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; PPP v5.1 (1,1,1); Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
10.3.1.1 - - [26/Jan/2011:08:57:34 +0000] "GET /html/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 686 "http://dhl-translation.accountis.net/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; PPP v5.1 (1,1,1); Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

Any ideas on the cause of this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another process is interfering with your timezone settings.

There's a pretty concise answer to this at ["what could cause Apache's time/timezone to change intermittently?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/26248/what-could-cause-apaches-time-timezone-to-change-intermittently). This can be particularly painful with Django -- as it doesn't handle juggling timezones very well -- and as such there are some good explanations in some Django-specific questions: [Django timezone confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518240/django-timezone-confusion-postgres-and-apache) and [Django timezone mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477079/django-timezone-mess)

The solution, in short, is to normalise your timezone settings. Ideally, use something like UTC for both server and applications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone has set the environment variable *TZ*. This can possibly be done in `.htaccess`.

Look for something like:

```
SetEnv TZ GMT
```